# Make it clearer that inviting a user to a room depends on the room the inviter is in, and not the invitee's chat profile

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-interface, usability, chat-profile

For the longest time I thought one can invite a chat user to the site's main chat room if and only if that user has used the site's main room recently. But it turns out, simply being in *whatever* room activates the option (first two screenshots are unedited apart from arrows):

**What I see when I'm **not** in a room:**

> [image: not in]

**What I see when I'm *in* a room:**

> [image: in]

**Proposed change for when the inviter is not in a room:**

> [image: proposal]

The proposed change will make it clearer that it depends on the inviter, and not the user being invited. (In my case, I realized that yesterday, after +5 years.)

---

From a comment: another possible wording: "You aren't in any rooms this user isn't in." Perhaps with a link to a help page that explains the conditions in detail: "A) you are in that room, B) the prospective invitee is not in that room, and C) the prospective invitee must have access to that room."

Comment: Portions of your question are unclear. You're trying to indicate differences of some user being in a room vs not being in a room, but you consistently don't say which user is in or not in a room for the criteria in your screenshots (i.e. for which user you're giving the current state). Personally, I believe I know what you're trying to say, because I already know how the system works, which is that the UI only gives you the option to invite a user into a room if you are already in that room and the user you're wanting to invite is not already in that room (which makes sense, IMO).

Comment: @Makyen: Where do I consistently not clarify which user it is? (Genuine question.) Here's what I wrote with added emphasis: "one can invite a **chat user** to the site's main chat room if and only if **that user** has used the site's main room recently"

Comment: Please use some annotation in your screenshots (e.g. the prototypical hand-drawn, red circles) to indicate what portion of the screenshot you're trying to get people to see. Without doing so, you waste people's time trying to determine what the differences are between the screenshots and if the differences they find are the ones you're to which you are trying to draw their attention. In addition, not making it easier for people to understand what you're trying to show results in more misunderstandings and people choosing to give up, rather than spend time trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Makyen: arrows added.

Comment: The places where you don't make this clear are: "simply being in whatever room activates the option", "Currently *not* in a room:", and "Currently in a room:". **Who** is currently in a room (you or the user you're inviting), which room?

Comment: @Makyen: and done, thx

Comment: The criteria for the invitation portion of the UI to be shown is actually that the inviter needs to be currently in a room which the prospective invitee is not currently in. As I mentioned above, you can only invite a user into a room where all of A) you are in that room, B) the prospective invitee is not in that room, and C) the prospective invitee must have access to that room. If there are no rooms which fulfill all three of those criteria, then there are no rooms into which you can invite a user, so the UI to invite a user is not shown.

Comment: So, rather than "Join a room to enable this option", perhaps something like "You aren't in any rooms this user isn't in". Perhaps have a tooltip which explains in more detail, such as "In order to invite this user to a room, you must be in that room and this user must both not be in that room and this user must have access to that room (i.e. they have to be able to join that room)."

Comment: @Makyen: added suggestion, thx, though the double negative you've used most find confusing. Final wording is likely up to SE.

Comment: If I’m understanding this correctly, it doesn’t have anything to do with a site’s “main” chatroom, isn’t it? Perhaps the first sentence can be edited to remove the reference to “the site’s main chat room”?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist: I'm explaining the use case that prompted this, with "thought", and clarification of how it works – "*whatever* room" – in the same paragraph. Without this it loses why I'm bringing this up, which I understand is important for feature requests. The title and the rest of the body makes no mention of the main room.

Comment: @ymb1 “The title and the rest of the body makes no mention of the main room.” — yes, that was in fact what confused me initially. I don’t insist you make a change to your post, though.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist: I'll try to figure something out anyway to make it clearer, thanks.